# JavaFX How to Clear Message

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx-2, message

The Code below is a snippet that is supposed to print a message if the password is incorrect, and print a different message when the password is incorrect.

```
pwBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                Label message = new Label();
                grid.add(message, 1, 7);

                if (!pwBox.getText().equals("T2f$Ay!")) {
                    message.setText("Your password is incorrect!");
                    message.setTextFill(Color.rgb(210, 39, 30)); //Red
                } else {
                    message.setText("Your password has been confirmed");
                    message.setTextFill(Color.rgb(21, 117, 84)); //Green
                }
                pwBox.clear();
            }

        });
```

When I purposefully enter an incorrect password the code prints red, if I do it again the color actually intensifies, and if I enter the correct password afterwards it just writes over the previous message. Is there simply a way to delete the message off of the grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `handle()` method is invoked every time the user presses "Enter" in the `pwBox`. This means that each time this happens, you create a brand new `Label` and add it into the same cell in the grid, placing it on top of anything that was previously placed there.

Instead, create the `Label` once, and update its text in the event handler:

```
        final Label message = new Label();
        grid.add(message, 1, 7);
        pwBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

                if (!pwBox.getText().equals("T2f$Ay!")) {
                    message.setText("Your password is incorrect!");
                    message.setTextFill(Color.rgb(210, 39, 30)); //Red
                } else {
                    message.setText("Your password has been confirmed");
                    message.setTextFill(Color.rgb(21, 117, 84)); //Green
                }
                pwBox.clear();
            }

        });
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding a message.setText(" ") before your conditional flow as shown below:

```
        pwBox.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            Label message = new Label();
            grid.add(message, 1, 7);
            message.setText("");

            if (!pwBox.getText().equals("T2f$Ay!")) {
                message.setText("Your password is incorrect!");
                message.setTextFill(Color.rgb(210, 39, 30)); //Red
            } else {
                message.setText("Your password has been confirmed");
                message.setTextFill(Color.rgb(21, 117, 84)); //Green
            }
            pwBox.clear();
        }

    });
```